# How to mount Azure Cloud Drive in azure java project

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I only see the C# API which can mount Azure Cloud Drive as a local disk.

So I try to write a small C# application to mount cloud drive and call it from startup.cmd but failed with below error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'mswacdmi, Versi
on=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its depe
ndencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'mswacdmi, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856a
d364e35'
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudDrive.InitializeCache(String cac
hePath, Int32 totalCacheSize)
```

Seems it cannot found mswacdmi.dll, but it still not works after I copy mswacdmi.dll to the application folder.

Comment: Have succeed after change the application target platform from x86 to x64. Sorry for not familiar with .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer to this question is to change applcation target platfrom from x86 to x64

Comment: so mounting the page blob as a drive is not possible in Java?

Comment: Yes, I don't see there is such API